# When is the nullspace unique in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection, projection-matrices

I am given the following:
$$
I - AA^T
$$
is a projection matrix onto the orthogonal complement of $< A >$.

So the nullspace of $I-AA^T$ is the subspace spanned by the set of vectors $x$ such that $(I-AA^T)x = 0$. Since we know the projection matrix projects x onto the orthogonal complement of $<A>$, then I believe this means the nullspace of $I-AA^T$ is $<A>$?

Based on this information, is it possible to determine when $<A>$ is unique?

Comment: Are some conditions missing? Unless all the singular values of $A$ are zeros or ones, $I-AA^T$ is not a projection.

Comment: It is not a projection since $(I-AA^T)^2 \neq I-AA^T$.

Comment: Hmmmm. I am initially not given any information about $A$. In a later problem, I see that $A$ has orthonormal columns and is not necessarily square.

Comment: After consulting with a colleague, it seems that we are supposed to assume A has orthonormal columns. So it is a projection matrix based on this condition.